# Why must these Java class names be fully qualified in Clojure?

Tags: java, import, clojure

I am defining a `definterface` to be used with a JAX-RS REST server ([RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)):

```
(ns com.example.server.resources.buildtime
  (:import [javax.ws.rs.core Cookie UriInfo]))

(definterface BuildTime
  (getBuildTime [^UriInfo info
                 ^Cookie security-cookie]))
```

When I AOT compile this class, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/UriInfo, compiling:(com/example/server/resources/buildtime.clj:13)
```

If I change the annotations to the following, the error goes away:

```
(definterface BuildTime
  (getBuildTime [^javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo info
                 ^javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie security-cookie]))
```

Why must the annotations have fully-qualified class names when the classes have been imported using `import:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gen-class` and `gen-interface` both require the class to be fully qualified as stated in the docs http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-interface and http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-interface. I am not aware why this is so.

Comment: Is that true for `definterface`? I cannot find docs on the Clojure API site (http://clojure.github.com/clojure/) for `definterface`.

Comment: `definterface` just does some macro parsing and then shells out to `gen-interface`, so if one has the requirement it seems like the other must.